# How do I display the content fetched from database(using the jsp file) on my html page using ajax?

Tags: html, css, ajax, jsp

I have a HTML file named Track.html, it contains a text box. We enter a 10 digit number and click the button to search. After validation an AJAX function is called, which sends the number to a jsp file and the input number is searched in the database, if the value is found in the database, the output should be displayed in another text box on the same HTML page(without changing the URL). But the problem is that it is not working.

To check that my jsp file is working properly, I did the following:
I'm using a form tag so in its action attribute I mentioned the jsp file and not calling the AJAX function, so after searching the input number it redirects to a new page and displays the corresponding content fetched from the database, but I want the content to be displayed on the same page.

Here is the HTML part:

```
<fieldset>
    <form method="post">
        <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Consignment Number</strong></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="cons" name="cons" autofocus="true" 
                    placeholder="Enter the 10 digit Consignment Number"
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><button onclick="search() 
                    <span>Search</span></button></td>
                    <td><span><input type="reset"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</fieldset>
<br>
<fieldset>
    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Your Package is at:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="result"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

Here is the AJAX function:

```
function search() {
  if (validate()) {
    var cnum = document.getElementById('cons').value;
    var obj1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    obj1.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if ((obj1.readyState == 4) && (obj1.status == 200)) {
        document.getElementById("result").value = obj1.responseText;

      }
    }
    obj1.open("get", "Trace.jsp?cn=" + cnum, true);
    obj1.send();
  }
```

Here is the jsp code:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
    try
    {
        int conum=Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("cn"));
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/postal_info","root","*******");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from trace;");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            int c=rs.getInt(3);
            if(conum==c)
            {
                out.println(rs.getString(6));
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println(e);
    }
%>
```

Comment: You forgot to put closing bracket  ```}``` of function search()

Comment: That is not error, maybe I have not copied it properly here...